# Change parameter value in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I would like to change parameter value in Verilog depending on 3 bit digital input pin value.
Here is a sample from my verilog code.

```
paramter real C_IP=0;

 always @ (reg_DACIP)
   begin
     case (reg_DACIP)
      3'b000 : C_IP = 0.8;
      3'b001 : C_IP = 0.6;
      3'b010 : C_IP = 0.4;
      3'b011 : C_IP = 0.2;
      3'b100 : C_IP = 0.0;
      3'b101 : C_IP = -0.2;
      3'b110 : C_IP = -0.4;
      3'b111 : C_IP = -0.6;
    endcase
end
```

When I compile I get this error:

```
ncvlog: *E,PANOTL: A parameter is not a legal lvalue [3.10(IEEE)].
      3'b001 : C_IP = 0.6;
```

I understand Verilog parameters are for constants, and therefore can not be changed during simulation. However what would be the best workaround over this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Parameters must be a constant, there is no way around it. A parameter can be a function of other parameters. A parameter can be changed to another constant at compile/elaboration time via `#()` in module instanciation or `defpram` (note `defpram` is planned for depreciation). A parameter will update to its new value if the paramter(s) it is derived from is changed during compile/elaboration. Examples of parameters derived from another parameter:

```
// nested conditional statement
parameter real C_I P = PARAM_DACIP==3'b000 ? 0.8 :
                       PARAM_DACIP==3'b001 ? 0.6 :
                       PARAM_DACIP==3'b010 ? 0.4 :
                       PARAM_DACIP==3'b011 ? 0.2 :
                       PARAM_DACIP==3'b100 ? 0.0 :
                       PARAM_DACIP==3'b101 ? -0.2 :
                       PARAM_DACIP==3'b110 ? -0.4 : -0.6;

// simple expression
parameter real C_IP = 0.2*(3'b100-PARAM_DACIP);

// pure static function (i.e. output only determined from input)
// Note: not all simulators/synthesizers support this
function real calc_C_IP( input [2:0] DACIP);
begin
  case (DACIP)
    3'b000 : calc_C_IP = 0.8;
    3'b001 : calc_C_IP = 0.6;
    3'b010 : calc_C_IP = 0.4;
    3'b011 : calc_C_IP = 0.2;
    3'b100 : calc_C_IP = 0.0;
    3'b101 : calc_C_IP = -0.2;
    3'b110 : calc_C_IP = -0.4;
    3'b111 : calc_C_IP = -0.6;
  endcase
end 
endfunction
parameter real C_IP = calc_C_IP(PARAM_DACIP);
```

if `reg_DACIP` must be a register, then `C_IP` cannot be a parameter. You can make it a regular `real`

FYI: `real` is not synthesizable

Comment: Thanks Greg. In your function example, what is PARAM_DACIP? DACIP is 3 bit logic input pin in my code. How do I pass it to calc_C_IP function?

Comment: Also in your fist nested conditional statement solution, what is PARAM_DACIP? How can I relate it to 3 bit  DACIP input pin?

Comment: @Sandeep, in your original code you used `reg_DACIP` which I assumed was a `reg` type, I changed `reg_` to `PARAM_` in my example to sugest it is a parameter and not a register. you an assume that `PARAM_DACIP` is defined as `parameter [2:0] PARAM_DACIP = 3'b100;` (or some other value)